# Accessibility read order Issue using addChildViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiaccessibility

I am facing problem with Accessibility read order issue.

I have a UIViewController in that 3 UIViewControllers added as childViewControllers.

NavigationController is added to the MainViewController.

When I turn on the accessibility, VO start reads from the childviewcontroller subviews and then moving to NavigationController. After reading the navigation bar Vo will not move down.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.suppressCart = YES;
    [self setupNavigationItems];

    // Set up the embedded navigation controller for the delivery/payment/review
    // subviews
    self.stepController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
    self.stepController.delegate = self;
    self.stepController.navigationBarHidden = YES;

    // Add it to this view controller as a child
    // Note: do not call begin/end appearance transitions
    [self addChildViewController:self.stepController];
    [self.view addSubview:self.stepController.view];

    self.stepController.view.frame = CGRectOffsetAndShrink(self.view.bounds, 0, TargetBreadcrumbButtonHeight);

}
```

self.stepController is used to push the view controllers with in the MainViewController.

Did any one face this issue before. Need help to resolve this.

Is there any way to make VO reads every element in Infinite Loop??

Thanks,
Rakesh

Comment: Your flow is not very clear? Please make it better read

Comment: Try adding `[self.stepController didMoveToParentViewController:self];`

Comment: Retro : VO is not reading from Navigation If childviews are present. Vo read the Child View Controller first and then Parent View Controller next.

Comment: Akhil : I added that line at the end of viewDidLoad. But no change in Accessibility.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. Did you ever resolve it?

Comment: No, I left that as it is...dint find the solution yet.